# magento 2 child theme location

Tags: magento2, theme, theme-fallback

I am not sure which directoy to setup my child theme for a theme I purchased.

The original directory of the theme is:

```
app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/fashion
```

there are a whole bunch of other themes (sub themes?) from the developer in the fastest directory as well, like so:

```
app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/sportswear
app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/outdoor
```

etc.

I want to make a child theme of fashion

So should my file structure be like this?

```
app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/fashion_child
```

and second question, when creating my theme.xml file is this the proper way to link to the fashion theme:

```
<parent>Codazone/fastest/fashion</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the theme in your own vendor folder instead of using the `Codazon` namespace. For example, `app/design/frontend/YourName/fashion`.

The parent tag that you gave should be correct.